# Call to undefined function bp_core_get_user_email() - Buddypress issue

Tags: email, buddypress

I am having a issue where I am trying to retrieve the email of the user who is logged in using Buddypress. Here is my code:

```
    global $bp; 
    echo bp_core_get_user_email($bp->loggedin_user->id);
```

Here is the error message that pops up when I open the php page:

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function bp_core_get_user_email() in /home/user/public_html/useremail.php on line 4"

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded WordPress & BuddyPress in your file `useremail.php`?
I see that it's the same level as wp-config.php. To make it know anything about WP/BP functions you need to do at least this:

`include ('./wp-load.php');`

Otherwise in your situation that php file will through errors everytime you will use non-standard php functions.

But the **true** way is to use WP - create:

1) a plugin that will handle all requests to a specific url

*OR*

2) create a page in WP dahsboard with a specific page template, and in its template file you can write whatever code you need or want.

Comment: I know you answered this a while ago but thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Other option to get the email:

$user_active = wp_get_current_user();

$user_mail = $user_active->user_email;